# Unity 4.3.4 + Sphero Plugin crashes when using example scenes included

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, sphero-api, sphero

I'm trying to build an iOS app from Unity 4.3 using Sphero Plugin for Unity 1.5 but whenever I tried to use one of three included examples the app just crashes as soon as app connected with Sphero.

Following is the error message I got from Xcode.

> Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /SourceCache/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-264.8/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1510
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

I also tried adding following to the Other Links Flag in Building Setting but it didn't solve the problem.

> -all_load

I'm using iOS7 on iPhone5s, Unity 4.3.4 and Xcode5. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: I've also tried the IOS SDK for Unity which I got from the github (https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK) but it still throws a same error message using Xcode 5.1 with iPhone5s.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the version of RobotKit.framework in assets/plugins/iOS with the latest version from the iOS github and see if it fixes it, I suspect it will.  You can grab it here: https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK